# How can I see the lines where matching patterns occur in grep for multiple patterns in multiple directories

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Thanks for all the input and effort, I've been able to find a solution to my "problem".

find . -type f -name '*.csv' -print0 | xargs -r0 grep -rn string1 | grep string2 | grep string3

Passing the output of find into multiple greps does it.

Comment: Please provide additional information, such as example data and command output to your question as currently it is unclear where the exact problem is. Note that "does not work" is not an adequate problem description.

Comment: Also please add the output of `grep --version` and `uname -a`. I have tested all of the provided solutions across different systems and can confirm that all of them work exactly as expected.

Comment: You run a very old version of `grep`. Please update to at least version 3 and try one of the solutions again.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `xargs` here.

```
-$ grep -rn other * | grep  alias | grep file                                                                                                                                                                 1 ↵
README.md:3:Should make aliases and other user specific config files way more conveniant.
```

Simply piping one `grep` into the next one should work just fine. It is enough to specify any flags with the first `grep`.

`man grep`

```
-n, --line-number
      Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.

-l, --files-with-matches
      Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  Scanning each input file stops upon first match.
```

---

#### retain the coloring of matches

To retain the coloring of the matches when piping to the next grep instance you can use the argument `color=always`.

For convenience you can set an alias like following:

```
alias grep='grep color=always'
```

Note that the color option could mess with the text when piping for example to `xargs`.

**Example:**

[image: example of grep highlighting]

Note that many distros already set an alias for grep, you might need to modify the existing one.

Comment: Unfortunately grep -rn -e '244959560909' -e '3271492050' returns lines where matches for just 244959560909 is found before it moves on to the next string. It doesn't give matching lines where both exist.

Comment: I think I tried this, problem is that it ignores the first 2 searches and only prints the 3rd, in this case 'file'

Comment: @pRieS by "print" you actually mean "highlight"? Because obviously the line gets printed.

Comment: By print, I mean highlighted. My current workaround involves getting the list of files out then cat .csv"|grep ''

Comment: Can you confirm that it is now working for you?

Comment: I'm sorry mashuptwice but it didn't work. I've resorted to using grep -rl 244959560909 * | xargs grep -l 3271492050 | xargs grep -l 2022-03-18 to see which files has those 3 matching strings in a line, cat the file and grep for one of those numbers until I find the line where they occur.

Comment: @pRieS "Didn't work" is an insufficient problem description to provide an answer.

Comment: Step 1       [ftp_admin@NTEL-SFTPSRV-CLS CVM_REPORT]$ grep -rl 2210655647 * | xargs grep -l 2348041124189 | xargs grep -l NSHO0010
25-02-2022/PRM_TRANSACTIONS_25-02-2022.csv
     [ftp_admin@NTEL-SFTPSRV-CLS CVM_REPORT]$
Step 2 [ftp_admin@NTEL-SFTPSRV-CLS CVM_REPORT]$ cat 25-02-2022/PRM_TRANSACTIONS_25-02-2022.csv|grep '2210655647'|grep 2348041124189|grep NSHO0010
Expected Result     2210655647,NSHO0010,Quickteller Web,2348041124189,N,18500,25-FEB-22 22:32:21,N,26612126,,SUCCESS,NSHO0010,Quickteller Web,Head Office

I'm trying to find a way that leads to the expected result without step 2

Comment: @pRieS The commands you run have nothing to do with my answer. Also please use backticks for code to improve the readability.

Answer (score 0):

Use egrep in the following manner:

### no matters appearances on different lines

`egrep -rn "244959560909|327149205|2022-03-18" *`

or

### matters appearances on same lines

`egrep -rn "244959560909.*327149205.*2022-03-18" *`

The problem that you're experiencing is that you're using several filters for what is being delivered from the previous commands, you're not feeding the whole list to the following command in the pipe, however egrep allows you the use of more complex regular expresions in your query.

HTH

PS, after having a brief conversation with @mashuptwice, seems that what you're looking for something like this:

```
for i in `egrep "244959560909|327149205|2022-03-18" -rl *`
do 
egrep -l "244959560909" $i && egrep -l "327149205" $i && egrep -l "2022-03-18" $i && echo $i
done|sort -u > matchingfiles.lst
egrep -rn "244959560909|327149205|2022-03-18" $(<matchingfiles.lst)
```

This addition to the code will enforce that the three strings appear inside the file and after that, the matching lines are displayed, I'm not removing the original solution since I'm a little bit confused.

HTH

PPS, as what is being looked for is the three strings in the same line original answer has to be changed into the following:

```
egrep -rn "244959560909.*327149205.*2022-03-18" *
```

HTH

Comment: OP made it clear that he tries to match all of the patterns, not any of those, which would resemble logical AND. Also the question is specifically about the coloring of the matches.

Comment: @mashuptwice, I apologize for not having understood the question correctly, you mean that he is looking for something like `egrep -rn "244959560909.*327149205.*2022-03-18" *`, because that will give every line that has that pattern, rather than every file rather than the solution suggested, taking into account that assuming that they are in such order, if the order varies it wil oblige to write the 6 variations, I', a little bit confused regarding this issue.

Comment: I was confused too at first, see the comments under my answer for clarification. Regarding your solution: That regex would of course work, but as you've pointed out that would only work if the matches are in order, which is unknown at this point.

Comment: I see, I think that the solution goes into constructing the list of files first and after that checking for every instance and having the 3 instances, performing the egrep that gives you the lines required. Cool I've it.

Comment: Note that `egrep` is [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383448/why-is-direct-invocation-as-either-egrep-or-fgrep-deprecated) in favor of `grep -E`

Comment: Hi Moses, actually what I'm trying to achieve is to view the line in a file which has all 3 matching strings. TO make it clearer, I have a directory with multiple subfolders containing thousands of CSV files. These CSV files contain random numbers and the date it was generated. I need to see the line in that CSV where the 3 search criteria occur. so Number A, Number B, Date

Comment: Then @pRieS, you have to use numberA.*numberB.*date, in your example this will be as follows:
`egrep -rn "244959560909.*327149205.*2022-03-18`
That will do the job.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.

Comment: @pRieS, I apologize for not having answered earlier, as it was sunday, I went out with the family, I tested the solution that I sent, however, chances are that there is some versioning problem, here:  `grep (GNU grep) 3.4 `

I've noticed that in the previous comment there was a syntax error, `egrep -rn "244959560909.*327149205.*2022-03-18" *` is the correct syntax.